# image button click inside gridview is not fetching datakeynames

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

Here i need to get the DataKeyNames on which row i click(in side tools column image button click)

but when i click on the imagebutton(pencil) it show the following error

[image]

my C# codes is

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        ImageButton btnedit = sender as ImageButton;          
        GridViewRow gvrow = btnedit.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        int sid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value);
        Response.Write(sid);
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    { 

    }
}
```

my Gridview source codes

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="StdId" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" EnableModelValidation="True" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Name") %></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                    <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Email") %></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile">
                    <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Mobile") %></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                    <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("City") %></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tools">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument="ImageButton" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/pencil.png" ToolTip="Click To Edit" AlternateText="Click To Edit"/>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server"  CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/cross.png" ToolTip="Click To Dletee" AlternateText="Click To Dletee"/>                            
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

            <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

        </asp:GridView>
```

please help me how to get the DatakeyName

Comment: GridView1_RowCommand sender is the gridview not the imagebutton

Comment: @sidhewsar Check my answer posted below..

Comment: Use this link it will help you http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add an `OnRowCreated` event to your gridview

```
OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"
```

An in .cs file add this ( set the Rowindex value in CommandArgument so you can get this on RoeCommand)

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ImageButton imgbtnEdit= (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkUrlID");
                imgbtnEdit.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();

                ImageButton imgbtnDelete= (ImageButton )e.Row.FindControl("lnkExtend");
                imgbtnDelete.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();

            }
        }
```

Now at your GridView1_RowCommand try this

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
  {
    int sid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value);
  }

}
```

Comment: i change the my Code as you told.. but it is showing an error

**The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled.**

Comment: did you added this "OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"" in your gridview markup? and remove CommandArgument="ImageButton" from the edit imagebutton.

Comment: Another important point is don't bind/fill your gridview on every postback. It should be in (!Ispostback)

Comment: use this link it will help you it answer all your question http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html